# Why am i getting Exception in if condition?

Tags: java

i just want to check 10 digit number of user input. user input can be 1 to 10 digit number.
i have also added `import java.util.* ;`

Problem: geting exception when user entered value greater than 10.
after using Long if user input is out of range then same error. 
**Error: Expection in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException**

i want to restrict user to enter only 1 to 10 digit only

Updated code

```
  for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
        if(b[i][0]==0)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the account number:");
                a=sc.nextLong();
                int lth = (int) Math.log10(a) + 1;
                if((lth <= 10) && (lth > 0)){
                    System.out.println("Account number is valid");
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("not a valid input");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does any 10 digit number fit in an `int`?

Comment: Why are you getting an int then converting it to a string, why not just get a string to begin with? If you do math with a value it is a number (int, double, long, etc) otherwise it is a String.

Comment: Max value of int is `2,147,483,647`

Comment: i have updated my code with long data type

Comment: Print your exception. *Throw* your exception. You may be hiding useful diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
a=sc.nextInt();
```

to

```
a=sc.nextLong();
```

or if you want string only then you can do following

```
String input=sc.next();
s1=a.toString();//no need for this
```

try following

```
try
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the account number:");
                String ip=sc.next();
                int lth = ip.length();
                if((lth <= 10) && (lth > 0)){
                    System.out.println("Account number is valid");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is data type of a?